# iPhone SDK: ReverseGeocoder updates too late?

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit, reverse-geocoding

I am using reverseGeocoder in a few places in my app.  This particular instance, I am using it to update details about my annotation.  I have created a property (MKPlacemark) which stores the new placemark each time the didFindPlacemark method runs.

The problem is, it always seems to be behind by one update.  Meaning, when my custom method calls my geoCoderPlacemark property, which gets updated from the didFindPlacemark method.  It returns the info for the LAST coordinates that I looked up, not the current.  So, it seems that somehow, that the didFindPlacemark method runs AFTER I recieve my property, when I assumed it was running BEFORE, so that I could get the updated placemark into another method.

What is the best way to go about doing this, and avoid this problem?  I really don't want to have to put all my code info the didFindPlacemark method.  It seems to much easier to have that method just update a property, but why would it update this AFTER I try to get it?

Answer (score 0):

I moved my code into the did didFindPlacemark and this has fixed my problem.